# Export SQL Server query to CSV using script

Tags: sql-server

Let say I have 1 query for remote SQL Server:

```
SELECT * FROM USER
```

And I would like to export using any kind of script without using manual intervention from SSMS. I expect the output to be like this:

```
id,username,firstName,lastName
1,amy,Amy,NULL
2,bob,Bob,Marley
3,cat,Cathy,NULL
```

How can I export into something like above?

---

I noticed there are few old discussions on this with variety of custom workaround that doesn't work for me. I prefer the exported file contains header, NULL value and without start/end quotes. Here's my closest script to achieve the result:

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM USER;" queryout export.csv -S 'localhost' -U sa -P 'password' -d 'mydatabase' -c -t  ','
```

Current output:

```
1,amy,Amy,
2,bob,Bob,Marley
3,cat,Cathy,
```

Comment: What is the issue with your current `bcp` script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQLCMD to achieve that like below:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'SQLCMD -E -W -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT * FROM dbname.schemaname.USER" -s "," | findstr /V /C:"-" /B > E:\export.csv'
```

Comment: i have modified your command to suits my need

`SQLCMD -b -S %DB_SERVER% -d %DB_NAME% -W -i %NOCOUNTSQL_FILEPATH%,%FILEPATH%  -s "," -r0 | findstr /V /C:"-" /B > %EXPORT_FILENAME%`